# Taylor approximation to multiplication of two 0-1 variables

Tags: taylor-expansion, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Let $Z$ and $Y$ be two 0-1 decision variables.

Is there any way to approximate the following term using Taylor approximation or any other approximations?

$$\sum_w \sum_s \sum_b \left(Z_{wbr}^s \sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') Y_{w'br'} \right)$$

where $r,r'=\{1,2\}$, with a condition if $r=1$ in $Z$, $r'$ should be equal $2$ in $Y$ and vice versa. i.e. $r$ and $r'$ are not equal.

Range of $w$ is $1,\dots,34$.
Range of $b$ is $1,\dots,158$.
Range of $s$ is $1,2,3$.

$p(w')$ is the probability of $w'$ with values between $0$ and $0.05$

The constraint is $\displaystyle \sum_w Y_{wbr}=1, \forall b, \forall r$

Introducing a new variable with related constraints is not helpful as the number of variables of the problem will be high and the problem becomes so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can linearize the product of two binary variables exactly by introducing one more variable and three constraints.  See [this Operations Research StackExchange post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

Alternatively, let $S_w = \sum_{w' \neq w} Y_{w', w}$ and linearize the product of $Z_w$ and $S_w$, as formulated [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable).

---

### Updated answer based on updated question:

Introduce decision variable $X_{w,b,r,r'}^s$ to represent $Z_{wbr}^s \sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') Y_{w'br'}$,
so that
$$\sum_w \sum_s \sum_b \left(Z_{wbr}^s \sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') Y_{w'br'} \right) = \sum_w \sum_s \sum_b X_{w,b,r,r'}^s.$$
We want to enforce
$$
X_{w,b,r,r'}^s =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{\sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') Y_{w'br'}} &\text{if $Z_{wbr}^s=1$}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
The following linear constraints do the job:
$$
0 \le \sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') Y_{w'br'} - X_{w,b,r,r'}^s \le 0.05(1-Z_{wbr}^s)\\
0 \le X_{w,b,r,r'}^s \le 0.05 Z_{wbr}^s
$$

Comment: The range of my parameters is high. So with the method of introducing a new variable witht three constraints, number of variables will become high and the problem will remain complicated to be solved.

Comment: I just added to my answer an alternative with a smaller formulation.

Comment: Thanks Rob Pratt

Comment: The main problem is as follows $\displaystyle \sum_w \sum_b \sum_s Z_{wb2}\sum_{w' \neq w} p(w') y_{w'b1}$, where w, b, s are parameters such that $w=1,...,34$,  $b=1,..,158$, and $s=1,2,3$. $P(w)$ is the probability of w that is between 0 and 0.05.

Comment: One constraint is $\displaystyle \sum_w y_{wb1}=1$

Comment: Applying the two recommended methods raised the variables to 1.5 million variables, which made the problem more complicated.

Comment: Any other recommendations?

Comment: Where is $s$ used?  Do $Z$ and $y$ have two indices or three?

Comment: Z has four indices. It should be $Z_{wbr}^s$ (sorry for the typo above), $Y$ has three indices $y_{wbr}$. I took part of the problem where $r=1$ with $Y$ and $r=2$ with $Z$. The other part when $r=1$ with $Z$ and $r=2$ with $Y$. They can't take the same $r$ in the same time.

Comment: OK, please add these updates to the question, and please correct the constraint.

Comment: Thanks again Rob Pratt. Another question: what if $z_{wbr}^s$ was replaced by a multiplication two $0-1$ variables that are $x_w^s$  and $y_{wbr}$. Should I introduce $z$ first and then follow the same steps as above? Will the introduced $z$ be considered as a $0-1$ variable?

Comment: Yes, if $Z$ is a product of binary variables, use the approach in the first link to linearize that, and keep the other constraints as above.

Comment: It worked perfectly Rob Partt and LINGO solver was able to get the solution. I have another issue the objective function has two non linear terms that are $\displaystyle \sum_s \sum_w \bigg(x_w^s *y_{wb1} \big(p(w)\big)+x_w^s*y_{wb2} \sum_{w' #NE# w} p(w') y_{w'b1}\bigg)$ and $\displaystyle \sum_w \bigg(y_{wb1} \big(p(w)\big)+y_{wb2} \sum_{w' #NE# w} p(w') y_{w'b1}\bigg)$ with the above constraints in addition to $d_b \bigg(y_{wb1$+y_{wb2}\sum_{w' #NE#w} p(w')y_{w'b1}\bigg) \le \sum_s V^s x_w^s$ where $x,y$ are binary decision variables and the rest are parameters.

Comment: After 24 LINGO could not get even a lower bound for the problem even using the above linearization process. Any recommended heuristic method?

Comment: Another question: what if, in the first original problem, the variable $Y$ was relaxed to be between $0$ and $1$. Will the above mention linearization process work?

Comment: The linearization I gave does not require integrality of $Y$.

Comment: Sorry I mean relaxing $Y$ in another problem as follows: $\sum_w$ $\sum_b$ $ \big(y_{wbr}$ $\sum_{w'}$ $ p(w')y_{w'br'}\big)$ with the same condition that $\sum_wy_{wbr}=1$ $\forall b, r$ and $0 \le Y \le 1$.

Comment: Any recommendations? even heuristic methods can help a lot.